# How do I show small numbers with scientific notation in Pandas Dataframe Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm working with a dataframe that on one column has numbers of different order of magnitude, the biggest is 0.315 and the smallest is 0.xxe-28.
My problem is that when I display the pd dataframe I get this:

[image]

Small numbers are rounded to 0.0

I'd like to show every number in scientific notation like: 3.15e-1, 6.55e-28, and so on.
How can I do that?
Thank you!

EDIT:
I found that `pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2E}'.format)` almost does the trick.
The problem is that now all the columns are in that format:

[image]

Is it possible to use set_option to specify a format just for one column?

Comment: Small numbers like 0.000000013 should be displayed in scientific notation by default. Have you changed any pandas configuration?

Comment: Hi, no I haven't. Not to my knowledge at least. How can I try to reset pandas configuration f that's the case? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the format for the whole dataframe with :

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:12.5e}'.format
```

Or set the format for each column individualy with :

```
output = df.to_string(formatters={
    'Coefficient': '{:12.4f}'.format,
    'P-value': '{:12.5e}'.format
})
print(output)
```